# Vue - Is it better to keep all props in one large mixin

Tags: vue.js

I have a component library where i would like to standardize the props, component etc.

Thoughts on combining them props/methods/other mixins/etx into one larger mixin

1. All property names would be the same
2. Remove duplicated code on refactoring to adjust components from local props/methods/computed/ to "global"
3. Not all components would have need for every piece of data contained within the mixin - point 4
4. Would tree shaking remove the unused code on Rollup?
5. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your component library is not constrained to using Vue 2 you might want to take a look at [Vue Composition API](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html) to share functionality (methods + reactive state) between different components.

Mixins might not be what you really want to be using because you kind of lose information as to what features/props/methods really will be put inside your component without re-checking the `mixin` code. You also might run into issues when component options get merged by Vue at runtime. Check out these posts for more information:
https://css-tricks.com/how-the-vue-composition-api-replaces-vue-mixins/
https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html

As for sharing `props`: What I've seen just yesterday (but not yet tried!) in a talk by John Leider - creator of Vuetify - is create a function that returns the props you want to reuse between components. Then you just call said function inside your props definition and use the spread operator.

Comment: Hi Philip! Nice props approach! Thanks for sharing.